# How to create a sitemap with page relationships

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sitemap

I'm currently trying to figure out a way to write a script (preferrably PHP) that would crawl through a site and create a sitemap.  In addition to the traditional standard listing of pages, I'd like the script to keep track of which pages link to other pages.

Example pages

```
A
B
C
D
```

I'd like the output to give me something like the following.

**Page Name:**  A

**Pages linking to Page A:**

- B
- C
- D

**Page Name:**  B

**Pages linking to Page B:**

- A
- C

etc...

I've come across multiple standard sitemap scripts, but nothing that really accomplishes what I am looking for.

---

**EDIT**
Seems I didn't give enough info. Sorry about my lack of clarity there.  Here is the code I currently have.  I've used simple_html_dom.php to take care of the tasks of parsing and searching through the html for me.

```
<?php

include("simple_html_dom.php");

url = 'page_url';

$html = new simple_html_dom(); 
$html->load_file($url);

$linkmap = array();

foreach($html->find('a') as $link):
    if(contains("cms/education",$link)):
        if(!in_array($link, $linkmap)):
            $linkmap[$link->href] = array();
        endif;
    endif;
endforeach;

?>
```

*Note: My little foreach loop just filters based on a specific substring in the url.*

So, I have the necessary first level pages.  Where I am stuck is in creating a loop that will not run indefinitely, while keeping track of the pages you have already visited.

Comment: I've updated my post with more details as to what is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Andy. That's something we can work with :) Please remember to upvote/accept answers that help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need two arrays to control the flow here. The first will keep track of the pages you need to look at and the second will track the pages you have already looked at. Then you just run your existing code on each page until there are none left:

```
<?php

include("simple_html_dom.php");

$urlsToCheck = array();
$urlsToCheck[] = 'page_url';
$urlsChecked = array();

while(count($urlsToCheck) > 0)
{
   $url = array_pop($urlsToCheck);
   if (!in_array($url, $urlsChecked)
   {
      $urlsChecked[] = $url;

      $html = new simple_html_dom(); 
      $html->load_file($url);

      $linkmap = array();

      foreach($html->find('a') as $link):
          if(contains("cms/education",$link)):
              if((!in_array($link, $urlsToCheck)) && (!in_array($link,$urlsChecked)))
                 $urlsToCheck[] = $link;

              if(!in_array($link, $linkmap)):
                  $linkmap[$link->href] = array();
              endif;
          endif;
      endforeach;
   }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Seeing the way you wrote this definitely makes sense to me, but in practice I got a fatal error for some reason.  I'm trying to figure out the cause, but maybe you would know off the top of your head.

**Fatal error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency?** for line 

`if((!in_array($link, $urlsToCheck)) && (!in_array($link,$urlsChecked))):`

UPDATE: I found the issue.  The in_array was being done using the object instead of the specific value I needed.

Comment: It might be in over-doing the arrays a bit, since `$link` is itself also an array. You could try replacing pretty much all instances of `$link` (except in the actual `foreach()`) declaration with `$link->href`